# How to provide permission to the other 3rd party APK read/write files in my own APK

Tags: android

I have a Provider and few files in my APK in ANDROID
I want other APK can read/write files programmatically to my data/data//files folder (Just like MMS providing permission to 3rd Party APK to read/write parts file).
How Can I provider permission to Other APK to read/write files to my above location in Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the Method `openFileOutput` from an Activity-Class with the flag `MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE` 
More Info see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)